# Need help decrypting with OpenSSL 3.0.8 Libraries

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, poco-libraries

I'm trying to write a service to decrypt a large number of openssl-encrypted content.  It works great with a simple command line program, but when I use the same code in a Poco (multi-threaded) server, I get:

> *error:1C800064:Provider routines::bad decrypt*

OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023)

I tried copying `std::strings` into C arrays, to see if that would help -- no luck

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas on how I can make this work?  I see old references to using mutex callbacks but the docs say they're not needed anymore.

Here's the code that always works on a CLI program but never works in my Poco service:

```c
int decodeAndDecrypt(const char          * dataIn,
                     const unsigned char * key,
                     const unsigned char * iv,
                     char                * dataOut,
                     int                 * outLen,
                     char                * errorMsg)
{
   while (ERR_get_error());
   BIO * bio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *)dataIn, -1);
   BIO * b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
   BIO * cipher =  BIO_new(BIO_f_cipher());

   BIO_set_cipher(cipher, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), key, iv, 0);
   BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

   BIO_push(cipher, b64);
   BIO_push(b64, bio);

   char * outPtr = dataOut;
   int max = *outLen;
   *outLen = 0;
   errorMsg[0] = 0;

   while (true)
   {
      char tmp[1024] = {0};
      int bytesRead = BIO_read(cipher, tmp, sizeof(tmp));
      if (bytesRead <= 0)
      {
         break;
      }
      if (bytesRead > max)
      {
         snprintf(errorMsg, ERR_SZ, "%s: result data exceeds maximum buffer size.", __func__);
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      snprintf(outPtr, max, "%s", tmp);

      outPtr += bytesRead;
      *outLen += bytesRead;
      max -= bytesRead;
   }

   if (*outLen == 0) // If no data was transferred, check for errors
   {
      unsigned long errNo(0);
      bool errorsFound(false);
      while ((errNo = ERR_get_error()))
      {
         errorsFound = true;
         array< char, 256 > temp;
         ERR_error_string_n(errNo, temp.data(), temp.size());
         strcat(errorMsg, temp.data());
      }
      if (errorsFound)
      {
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
   }

   BIO_free_all(cipher);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "bad decrypt" means that there is something wrong with your incoming data.  Either it's corrupted or your using the wrong cipher or your key/iv are different to the encrypted versions.  Sometimes it may be the versions of openssl defaults as well (i.e. encrypted with version x and attempted to decrypt with version y of openssl lib).  Your code could be improved but I don't think it's the code's problem.  Try to trace/dump the data/keys/iv and compare across platforms with the same data/setup.  With the same data/setup it should work.

Comment: @ShanePowell thank you for your reply.  Since the exact same decrypt code with the same OpenSSL libraries works differently based on Poco server vs simple CLI program, I don't think it's an OpenSSL version problem.  I tried tracing the OpenSSL code until it disappeared into some assembler routine, at which point I was lost.

Comment: I don't think tracing the openssl code is your answer. If it fails on one platform it should fail on another platform (given all other things are equal).  So if you take the input data/key/iv from one platform it should then fail on another platform.  If it does work on another platform then it's something about your openssl setup/library and/or openssl version changes.  If it doesn't work, then it's your data.  Trace the data back to where it was generated making sure nothing got corrupted somewhere alone the line.  That's how I would attack this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realize that EVP_aes_256_cbc() **must** have a 256 bit key and a 128 bit IV.  After making sure that both values were the correct length and zero padded for shorter values, this routine began to work properly.

Comment: That's normal for most of the AES encryption modes - if you get the IV and key sizes correct, you'll get *something* out of the decryption process.  It might be garbage, but it will come out.  Pretty much the only exception is an AES-GGM decrypt will fail authentication.  I also don't *believe* OpenSSL's AES-CBC implementation requires you to pad your plaintext before encryption, but I'm not totally certain.